# Schreiben deutsche Muttersprachler Ziffern von Zahlen normalerweise in der Reihenfolge in der sie sie sagen?

Tags: numbers

Nehmen wir als Beispiel die Zahl 36. Schreibt Ihr (mit einem Stift auf Papier) die Ziffern in der Reihenfolge, wie sie beim Sprechen ausgesprochen werden, also zuerst die 6 und dann die 3? Also von rechts nach links?

Ich möchte das aus Neugier wissen.

Comment: Natürlich nicht, das ist bei 753 auch ziemlich unpraktisch, wenn der Platz in der Mitte dann nicht reicht.

Comment: Meine eingebildete Erinnerung sagt: das war ein schweres Stück Denkarbeit damals in der Schule, diese zweistelligen Zahlen flüssig von links nach rechts an die Tafel zu schreiben. Zumal ich sie aufsagen und damit rechnen konnte bevor ich sie schreiben konnte. Also kann ich mir vorstellen, dass so mancher einen Knoten hat(te).

Comment: @guidot es gibt viele Personen, die Zahlen so schreiben (aus welchem Grund auch immer). Die Lücken sind dann etwas größer, aber es ist halt eine Gewöhnung und irgendwann weiß man eben, wie breit man die Zahlen immer schreibt und welcher Platz gelassen werden muss.

Comment: Eine Freundin von mir schreibt gerade ihre Psychologie-Masterarbeit darüber. Es gibt scheinbar signifikante Unterschiede in der Zahlenverarbeitung zwischen Sprechern von Sprachen, die Zahlen "linear" ordnen, und von solchen wie dem Deutschen, eben _weil_ es schwerer ist, die gesprochene Zahl dann in der Schrift "umzuordnen".

Comment: Wir schreiben Zahlen arabisch/indisch weil es viel einfacher ist so mit ihnen zu rechnen. Stellt Euch mal die römischen Buchstaben vor ... entsetzlich :-) Allerdings sind die Sprechweisen sehr unterschiedlich. Die Franzosen nehmen als Basis auch die 20 und 4, englisch stellt die Zehnerstelle voran beim sprechen, deutsch halt die Einerstelle. Es ist eben uneinheitlich.

Comment: Bei Listen längerer Zahlen (Tabellen) schreibe ich immer von rechts nach links um zu garantieren, das die Dezimalstellen immer untereinander stehen (und bei Kommazahlen kommt erst das Komma und von dort geht es nach links mit den Vorkommazahlen und dann nach rechts mit den Nachkommastellen).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich denke nicht, dass *allgemein* gesagt werden kann, wie "Muttersprachler" die Zahlen aufschreiben.

Ich schreibe die Zahlen **NICHT** so wie es in der Sprache bezeichnet/gesagt wird, so wie es wohl die meisten machen. Also zu deinem Beispiel: Bei 36 schreibe ich IMMER zuerst die 3 und dann die 6 (von links nach rechts). Auch bei mehr als zweistelligen Zahlen.

Ich kenne aber Personen, die Schwierigkeiten mit Zahlen haben (Legasthenie) und es einfachheitshalber so aufschreiben wie man es sagt, also wie du in deiner Frage schon beschrieben hast: bei 36 zuerst die 6 und dann links von der 6 die 3 -> 36. Dazu kann ich mir auch vorstellen, das *Fremdsprachler* es auch so aufschreiben, auch einfachheitshalber, und weil man es nicht gewohnt ist (Englisch, Französisch), die Zahlen anders aufzuschreiben, als man die Zahl ausspricht.

Diese Frage kann leider nicht klar beantwortet werden, obwohl die **Mehrheit** der *Muttersprachler* von *links nach rechts aufschreiben* und nicht wie man es ausspricht.

Comment: @CarstenS: Oh, das stimmt wohl. Danke für den Hinweis :)

Answer (score 4):

Wie schreiben englischsprachige Menschen Zahlen wie 13 oder 17? Auch in *thirteen* und *seventeen* wird zuerst die rechte Ziffer ausgesprochen und dann erst die linke. Das ist exakt gleich wie bei den deutschen Zahlwörtern *dreizehn* und *siebzehn.*

Der Unterscheid ist nur, dass im Englischen nur die Zahlen von 13 bis 19 auf diese Weise ausgesprochen werden, im Deutschen zusätzlich aber auch 21 bis 29, 31 bis 39 usw.

Die Antwort lautet also:
Jeder Mensch schreibt die Ziffern der Zahl 36 in genau derselben Reihenfolge, in der er auch die Ziffern der Zahl 13 schreibt, und diese Reihenfolge hängt nicht von der Muttersprache ab.

Answer (score 0):

Kommt darauf an. Wenn jemand seine Telefonnummer nennt (15 24 36) dann schreibe ich mit der Hand die Ziffern in der Reihenfolge wie sie gesprochen werden - 5 mit Lücke, 1 davor, 4 mit Lücke usw. damit ich keine Ziffer vergesse. Wenn ich meine eigene Telefonnummer schreibe, dann links nach rechts. Auf dem Computer immer links nach rechts weil alles andere sehr unpraktisch ist.

Comment: Das ist eigentlich keine schlechte Antwort, ich weiß nicht warum jemand sie downvotet hat. Danke jedenfalls